# How do I access "netdev_dbg" logs?

Tags: networking, boot, logs, debugging, error-handling

I'm trying to debug my device which uses the qc7000 driver (qca_spi.c)

It has a bunch of useful netdev_dbg messages scattered around.

How can I access the logs where these messages are being stored?

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** These prints should always show in /proc/kmsg, so you can run

```
$ cat /proc/kmsg
```

To view them. Each entry even specifies the log level next to it so look for entries that start with '<7>'.

**More Information:** netdev_dbg() is a macro defined in include/linux/netdevice.h, which eventually results in a call to netdev_printk(KERN_DEBUG, ...). This results in a printk() call with the KERN_DEBUG log level. Every system has its own printk configuration, which defines which levels will be printed to dmesg and which will be ignored[1]. Still, all printk calls will print to /proc/kmsg, regardless of the log level.

You can check the dmesg settings by running:

```
$cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

The out put of this file has 4 values: current, default, minimum and boot-time-default levels. You are interested in 'current'. For me, the debug level after reboot was 3 (KERN_ERR). This means that any printk call with level >= 3 will be ignored:

```
$cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
3       4       1       7
```

You can change this in a number of ways, I used dmesg -n  and set it to '8' which should print debug level printk calls:

```
$sudo dmesg -n 8
$cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
8       4       1       7
```

After doing this you should be able to see debug prints in dmesg.

Notes:

- Since KERN_DEBUG equals to '7' you need to set the current log level to '8' in order for it to show.
- There are some other settings that might overwrite the dmesg settings so in any case /proc/kmsg should be the best option for viewing debug messages.
- Each call to 'cat /proc/kmsg' flushes the log so on the second call it might be empty if no new messages arrive.

[1] More information about printk and print levels: https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Log_Levels